# Get the same Findbugs bugs in Maven and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, findbugs

I managed to run findbugs within my maven build process, and I also have findbugs configured in eclipse. However when running in Eclipse and Maven I get different bugs, and I can't seem to find a setting, where the number of bugs matches in Eclipse and Maven.

My Maven settings is like this:

```
<version>2.5.2</version>
<configuration>
        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
        <threshold>Normal</threshold>
        <effort>Default</effort>
        <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
        <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
        <findbugsXmlWithMessages>true</findbugsXmlWithMessages>
</configuration>
```

And in Eclipse I have:

```
Findbugs Version: 2.0.1
Analysis Effort: Default
Minimum Rank to report: 20
Minimum Confidence to Report: Medium
Reported categories: All
```

With those settings, I get more bugs in Eclipse. My main problem is, that I can't even match the different settings between maven and eclipse.

Comment: Are they both using the same version of FindBugs? Maven will derive the version from the pom file, but Eclipse will depend upon what you installed. Also, which one produces more bugs?

Comment: I edited the post to answer your questions, but I'm not really sure about the versions... 2.5.2 is the version of the findbugs-MavenPlugin, while 2.0.1 is the version of the findbugs-EclipsePlugin, I'm not sure which version of findbugs those two actually use.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [m2e-code-quality](http://m2e-code-quality.github.com/m2e-code-quality/), which includes an m2eclipse 'connector' that should ensure your Eclipse FindBugs configuration matches the configuration specified in your pom.

Comment: The update site in the link is broken (404), it looks like this is the correct one: http://m2e-code-quality.github.com/m2e-code-quality/site/

Comment: No, that one doesn't seem to work as well. Is m2e-code-quality available?

Comment: @Timo I used : http://m2e-code-quality.github.io/m2e-code-quality/site/1.0.0/ as the eclipse update site

Answer (score 1):

I'm having exactly the same problem. There is a mismatch between settings available in Eclipse (using FindBugs 2.0.1) and the Maven plugin (version 2.5.2).
One setting that is missing from the Maven plugin is 'confidence'.
Using another piece of software to match the configurations doesn't address the issue because the Eclipse matching just highlights a problem. I want certain bugs reported from the Maven build completely independently of Eclipse that aren't being reported. It just happens that it is possible to have them reported in Eclipse.